# Single type compile time list: concat with clang

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr, compile-time

I'm using a "fixed type compile-time list" for a project of mine. Recently I tested this project for compatibility with different compilers and I noticed the clang (3.8) can't compile my implementation.
This error appeared:

```
error: expected expression return

List<T, sizeof...(Ints1) + sizeof...(Ints2)>(this->get<Ints1>()..., rhs.get<Ints2>()...);                                                          
                                                                                   ^
```

The following part is extracted from my implementation of the compile time list:

```
template<class T, size_t TNum>
class List;

template<class T, size_t TNum>
class List: public List<T, TNum - 1>
{
protected: 
    T data;
    template<size_t ... Ints1, size_t ... Ints2>
    constexpr List<T, sizeof...(Ints1) + sizeof...(Ints2)> _concat(const List<T, sizeof...(Ints2)> rhs, std::index_sequence<Ints1...>, std::index_sequence<Ints2...>) const
    {
        return List<T, sizeof...(Ints1) + sizeof...(Ints2)>(this->get<Ints1>()..., rhs.get<Ints2>()...);
    }

    template<class ... TArgs>
    constexpr List(T d, TArgs&& ... arg)
        : List<T, TNum - 1>(std::forward<TArgs>(arg)...), data(d)
    {
        static_assert(TNum != sizeof...(TArgs), "Number of arguements and list size does not match!");
    }        

    template<size_t TNum2, typename Indices1 = std::make_index_sequence<TNum>, typename Indices2 = std::make_index_sequence<TNum2>>
    constexpr List<T, TNum + TNum2> concat(const List<T, TNum2>& rhs) const
    {
        return this->_concat(rhs, Indices1(), Indices2());
    }

    template<size_t TI>
    constexpr T get() const
    {
        static_assert(TI < TNum, "Element out of valid range!");
        static_assert(TI >= 0, "Element out of valid range!");
        return static_cast<List<T, TNum - TI> >(*this).get();
    }
};
```

Additional there are two spezialisation for TNum=1 and TNum=0 that are missing in this example. I can add them if needed

I hope you can help my find the error that creates this problem

Edit:
Thanks Jarod42 for the answer. With his help i found this: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) That exlains things further.

Comment: You might be missing template keyword before `get` in a place specified by the compiler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` is missing in `rhs.get<Ints2>()`:

it should be

```
rhs.template get<Ints2>()
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/220947d69a5f0694)

Comment: Thx, this works fine. Not sure why VC++ and gcc don't have an issue with this.